# PHP/CSS: Backgrounds for DIVs are there, but are invisible

Tags: php, css, background, invisible

Edit to Add: Here is the link: http://www.svvreewijkdevaan.nl/nl/fotos-van-vroeger/

In a PHP file I generate a series of div's with images as backgrounds using the following line (contained in a while-loop):

```
echo ' <div class="pic" style="background:url('.$directory.'/'.$file.') 
no-repeat 50% 50%; background-size: cover; background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center; " > 
<a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" data-lightbox="image-1"
title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.' 
</a> </div> ';
```

I note that, as you can see in the above line of code, I do not use the background-image property, but the background property. Also, the div's get a fixed width and height from a style-sheet.

These are thumbnail-images, so - with the help of the Lightbox2 plug-in - I've made it so that when you click on one of these div's, a lightbox opens that shows the same image (i.e. the same jpg-file as used in the thumbnail-div), but larger. [I know that, in terms of loading times, it may not be a good idea to use the same image-file both as a thumbnail and for the large picture, but that's irrelevant here.]

Most of this works correctly:

- the div's get the correct height and width, and are clickable;
- when I click on a thumbnail-div, a light window opens that correctly displays the same image-file as used as background for that div.

The problem, however, is that the thumbnails themselves (the images used as backgrounds) are not visible. These files are obviously located correctly (otherwise the lightbox wouldn't display them either), and you can click them to see the image in a lightbox, but you don't see anything of any thumbnail-image.

So what I get is a big white page with many small white clickable area's (the thumbnail-div's), and it's only when you click that you actually see an image (i.e. in the lightbox).

It's also strange that this very same construction worked without problems on my previously used server. On the new server, the thumbnails are simple invisible.

Thus, the question is : why are the divs' backgrounds invisible?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: kindly, can you provide a demo link such as jsfiddle just to help us see what you got

Comment: Try to clean your Browser cache.

Comment: @Mustafa-elhelbawy: Here is the link: http://www.svvreewijkdevaan.nl/nl/fotos-van-vroeger/
(I'll also put it in the Question.)

Comment: @ Andreas: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Please put the generated HTML in the question and create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to see what goes wrong in your code snippet, because we cannot see what the output of your PHP code is. And it's also hard to find the right snippet in your page based on the PHP code.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Unfortunately, at this time, due to time constraints, I cannot do more than provide the actual link itself - and hope it may be enough for someone to spot the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use Single Quotation marks `''` for your URL

```css
    background: url('/wp-content/gallery/Fotos_van_vroeger/Speeltuin De Vaan ZW_0003.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

PHP:

```
echo ' <div class="pic" style="background:url(\''.$directory.'/'.$file.'\') 
no-repeat 50% 50%; background-size: cover; background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center; " > 
<a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" data-lightbox="image-1"
title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.' 
</a> </div> ';
```

**Edit: (t784956)**
*warning the next code is just an example do not copy&paste*

[can i use data()?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)

PHP:

```
echo '<div class="pic" data-backgroundurl="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'">
  <a href="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" data-lightbox="image-1" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank"></a>
</div>';
```

```js
$(".pic").each(function(index) {
  var bUrl = $(this).data("backgroundurl");
  console.log(bUrl);
  $(this).css("background-image", "url('" + bUrl + "')")
});
```

```css
.pic {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pic" data-backgroundurl="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/">
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" data-lightbox="image-1" title="x" target="_blank">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="pic" data-backgroundurl="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nightlife/">
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nightlife/" data-lightbox="image-1" title="y" target="_blank">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="pic" data-backgroundurl="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics/">
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics/" data-lightbox="image-1" title="z" target="_blank">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it as soon as possible.

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask more :)

Comment: OK, so I originally I had this: 
echo ' <div class="pic '.$nomargin.' '.$oddevenq.'" style="background:url('.$directory.'/'.$file.') ';

You are correct that in the generated HTML there are NO quotation marks around the URL, which is suspect indeed.

However, I'm already using the single quotation marks as part of my PHP (i.e. as string delimiters in PHP), and I'm already using double quotation marks to delimit my CSS-string (which is part of the PHP-string). So it seems I can use neither singles nor doubles quotation marks to put around the URL.

Comment: However, maybe I could string smaller strings together, will have a look.

Comment: do you use js or better jQ ? @Holland

Comment: Well, the Lightbox2-plug-in surely uses JavaScript and probably jQuery, why?

I've now apparently succeeded in putting single quotation marks around around the URL. I say apparently, because the Firefox Inspector tool seems to cut away part of the URL string, showing only part of it, and I can't seem to expand it to check whether the URL-string is generated correctly... 
Would it be possible to confirm that there are now single quotes around the background-URL's in the link given above?

Comment: Yes but not correctly, giive me 30mins and i'll try to give you a solution :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask a separate question about the Firefox Inspector tool cutting away part of the URL-string.

Comment: @Holland a made an edit, it is an example you need to shape a little.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see, the key may be using the escape character! I'm going to try it out. I'll report back, but this may take some time.

Comment: Yes, it works! Many thanks, and this will teach me not to forget about quotation marks and the escape character!

Comment: Again no problem, feel free to contact me if something is not working fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have some duplicate properties... and you are missing some quotes.
Try to change your code to something like this (not tested):

```
$imagePath = $directory.'/'.$file;

echo ' <div class="pic" style="background:url(\''.$imagePath.'\')  no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;" > 
<a href="'.$imagePath.'" data-lightbox="image-1"
title="'.$title.'" target="_blank">'.$title.' 
</a> </div> ';
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go and look again. If it's really a matter of missing quotes, that would be silly indeed. ;-) Actually I assumed the line of code was correct since it worked without problem on the other server. Also, I slightly simplified the code in my Question (so as no to make things more complicate than necessary), I hope I didn't make a mistake there. In any case, I will take another look at the syntactic correctness of this line of code.

Comment: Yes it's only about the quotes and you had some duplicates properties. You have the background with no-repeat and 50% 50% then you have another property background-repeat, background-position. If you want to use the 2 properties you need to change the first one to background-image and remove the no-repeat 50% 50% part. You can't combine them :)

Comment: BTW much appreciated, I wasn't the one who downvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

for the following class you really have the image and its path is right also:

```
.kader-div1 {}
```

the following class inside the above class and has a white background just remove the background color from the following class

```
.kader-div2 {}
```

and this will help you to show the background, by the way be careful that this class founded more than one time in your css file when you remove white background remove it from the multiple snippets for the same class